# How to Activate Speakerphone in Android 13

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Could someone please post a solution that ACTUALLY works on current Android 13. There are several posting but they don't work on Android 13 using Xamarin. I don't have Xamarin usage restrictions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1053246/how-to-turn-on-speakerphone-for-incoming-call-in-x

this article fails to activate the Speakerphone. I even simplified the problem by creating a Button event with Toggling the Speakerphone and that does not work either.

Comment: please do not post duplicate questions

Comment: Those question target exclusively Xamarin. My question is for Android in general. Its possible that Xamarin has an inherent bug that may not work with Android.

Comment: your prior question links directly to a native Android bug report

Comment: But this bug exists since 2020 with Xamarin. Are you saying that no one can activate Speakerphone after Android 10 no matter what platform they use to develop the code? However if one can activate Speakerphone on Android 11, 12, 13 then how are they activating it? Its clear from all my post that I am struggling with clarity on this.

Comment: I would very much appreciate it if someone can mentor me for getting ANY solution!!!